# Quotient of an affine scheme under the action of a finite group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, group-actions, schemes, affine-schemes

I am trying to solve Exercise 2.3.21 from Liu’s book. I have a finite group $G$ acting on an affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec}A$, and I want to show that the quotient scheme $X/G$ exists and is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}A^G$.

I have defined a map from the quotient $X/G$ to $\operatorname{Spec}A^G$, sending the class of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ to the intersection of $A^G$ and all the primes of the orbit.

However, I am not able to find an inverse. Namely, given a prime in $\operatorname{Spec}A^G$, I would like to map it to the ideal it generates in $A$, but I am afraid that this may not be prime.

Comment: I don't understand. what do you mean an inverse to the map from $X/G\to spec A^G$?.$X/G$ is not a defined scheme you don't know even if this is exist or not and then you only have it's universal property. the best thing you can do is to prove that $Spec A^G$ satisfy this universal property. for this you have to use exercise 20.

Comment: You are right. However, since I know from another exercise that $X/G$ is a locally ringed space, I was hoping to prove that $X/G$ and $\operatorname{Spec}A^G$ are isomorphic as locally ringed space. I am not sure if this makes sense, probably your reasoning is more elegant.

Comment: no it's ok, but do you know the construction of the locally ringed space $X/G$? by the part a,b,c of 20 shows the underlying topological space of $spec A^G$ is equal to the quotient topological space and part $d$(with a little effort) shows that $O(U)=O(p^{-1}(U))^G$and this is exactly the locally ringed space representing  $X/G$

Comment: you don't have to worry about prime ideals because you are working in the setting of locally ringed space. the things about prime ideals you need to know are providing exercise 20

Comment: Now I think I understand, I only needed to turn the page... thank you @ali